# Selenium find multiple elements by class name

Tags: python, css, selenium

```
<div id="root">
    <div class="abc1">
        <div class="abc2">
            <a class="iwantthis"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="abc3">
            <a class="iwantthis"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the simplified version of the page I have. I want to select all elements with class name "iwantthis". I tried the following, but it can find any elements.

```
divs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('iwantthis')
```

Do I need to add extra arguments if the element is in a div which is also in a div?

Comment: in CSS selection `class` needs dot in `selector('.iwantthis')` and `id` will need `#` like `selector('#root')`, etc.. So you have to learn CSS. You have these rules also when you use CSS in JavaScript or in files `.css`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your css_selector is based on the class name, your expression should be:

```
divs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.iwantthis')
```

or

```
divs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.iwantthis')
```

So you just missing a dot `.` in your css_selector.
You can also try the following XPath:

```
divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class,'iwantthis')])
```

Comment: Despite the misleading variable name, the element in question has tag `a` so selectors should not look for a `div`.

Comment: Thanks, the variant with the Xpath worked :)

Comment: Well, it means there are more than a single `iwantthis` class name there :) Or at least in some cases.